# Dependency not found - Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

I have recently added axios to a file called `services.js` so it's better organised. This file is on my root folder.

@/services.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: " server url here",
});

export const api = {
  get(endpoint) {
    return axiosInstance.get(endpoint);
  },
  post(endpoint, body) {
    return axiosInstance.post(endpoint, body);
  },
};
```

Then I have a component called `Post.vue` in my view folder:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { api } from "@/services.js";

export default {
  name: "Post",
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      post: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPost() {
      api.get(`/post/${this.id}`).then(response => {
        this.post = response.data;
        console.log(this.post);
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getPost();
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

I also have a router.ts file with all my routes:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Podcasts from "../views/Podcasts.vue";
import Post from "../views/Post.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: "/podcasts",
      name: "podcasts",
      component: Podcasts,
    },
    {
      path: "/post/:id",
      name: "post",
      component: Post,
      props: true,
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

It's giving me a dependency error like @/services.js did not exist.

Unsure what's wrong at this stage.

Thanks a lot in advance for helping out

Comment: did you tried `npm install`

Comment: yes I did - still same error

Comment: Did you try the import statement without the `@` sign using "normal" relative import paths? Maybe your webpack-config does not know how to handle the `@`

Comment: I have tried "/services.js" and "services.js" and nothing - I have another project same vue version etc and works absolutely fine.

Comment: is `@` a resolve alias in your webpack config? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: Thanks @Phil that solved my problem! thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a standard Vue CLI project, the `@` symbol resolves to `/src`

If your file is in the root of your project try

```js
import { api } from '@/../services'
```

But personally, I'd move it into `src`

---

You can [check the Webpack configuration](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config) using

```sh
vue inspect
```

Look for the [`resolve.alias` rules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias).

Answer (score 1):

Check your webpack configuration, depends on the version of webpack you have, there should be an alias `@` like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname) // check the path here
    }
  }
};
```

Or if you are using vue.config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    name: name,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname)// check the path here
      }
    }
  },
```

Make sure the path is correctly set up. You mentioned you have another project working fine, which makes it a good reference.

Comment: thanks a lot - Where can I find the webpack config file?

Comment: @Rpx, it depends, it could be `webpack.config.js` or a section `configureWebpack` in your `vue.config.js`